# Calculation screen coordinates of verticle in openGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, vector, matrix, opengl-es

I want to calculate screen x and y coordinates of same vertex for clipping.
It does in shader actually and i just want to do the same thing in my C-code.
My shader is

```
uniform mat4 u_MvpMatrix;
attribute vec4 a_Position;
void main(){
    gl_Position = u_MvpMatrix * a_Position;
}
```

gl_Position.x and gl_Position.y is screen.x and screen.y coordinates of verticle i assume?

There is my C-code, where model_view_projection_matrix is the same matrix, that i put in shader as u_MvpMatrix.

```
vec4 screen_coords;
vec4 vertex = {0,0,0,1};
mat4x4_mul_vec4(screen_coords, model_view_projection_matrix, vertex);

static inline void mat4x4_mul_vec4(vec4 r, mat4x4 M, vec4 v)
{
int i, j;
for(j=0; j<4; ++j) {
    r[j] = 0.f;
    for(i=0; i<4; ++i)
        r[j] += M[i][j] * v[i];
}
}
```

But it gives me the vector screen_coords, where screen_coords.x and screen_coords.y independed to model Z-coordinate. screen_coords.x only depend to model x-position, and screen_coords.y analogical. But both useless screen_coords.z and screen_coords.w depend to model Z-coordinate.

Do I use wrong multiplication function or some another wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> gl_Position.x and gl_Position.y is screen.x and screen.y coordinates of verticle i assume?

No, they're in clip coordinates. To get from clip to screen space you have to

1. perform coordinate homogenization `p_NDC = p_clip/p.w` (now coordinates are in NDC space)
2. map NDC to viewport coordinates `p_window = (p_NDC + 1)/2 * viewport.{width, height} + viewport{x, y}`

Another pitfall people often trip into is that OpenGL's matrix element ordering is column major, which "looks" (but isn't) transposed standard notation. I see you're using code from my `linmath.h` library, in which I took care of that, i.e. calculations are done column major and if you fetch from and pass to OpenGL `mat4x4` it's in the right order.

Comment: You also need to handle the depth range to compute screen-space Z and screen-space W is 1/clip_W. Those details *might* be relevant considering the original question talked about screen-space Z and W.